# libGDX(android) Разрешение экрана и использование ресурсов

Tags: android, libgdx

Познаю libGDX. Сразу столкнулся с вопросом о ресурсах и поддержки разных разрешений экранов. В libGDX есть папка для ресурсов ***assets*** и папка ***res/drawable*** (обе в пакете андроида).

1. В какую из них мне нужно закинуть изображения/атласы для отрисовки игровых объектов?
2. Нужно ли учитывать dpi изображений (mdpi, hdpi и другие)?
3. Какой инструмент использовать для сохранения пропорций изображения на разных экранах?

Если в чистой Android Studio понятно, что ***разметка.xml*** подтянется под размеры экрана устройства, то как с этим обстоят дела в libGDX?

Приведу пример: У меня есть базовый экран 240х400 пикселей. На этом экране рисую квадрат 100х100 пикселей. Далее я начинаю менять размеры экрана на большие, тем самым квадрат начинает уменьшаться. ***Как мне избежать уменьшения квадрата?*** Я понимаю, что должен использовать OrthographicCamera и относительные величины, но не могу разобраться как именно я должен их использовать.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо.

Comment: Методами LibGDX файлы достаются из папки assets. Drawable это уже зона андроида и подгружается стандартными методами Android sdk, что надо думать ломает концепт кроссплатформенности

Comment: @Yellastro ок, с папками стало понятно. А что делать с dpi и пропорциями изображений на разных экранах? Какой инструмент, для этого, используют в libGDX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Все изображения в ***assets***.
2. LibGDX сам всё учитывает, вам нужно только объявить размеры поля зрения камеры.
3. Приведение к одной константе, будь то ширина или высота, другую уже подсчитывать при запуске из разрешения экрана.

Моя реализация:

```
float wi=(int)state.main.dims[0]/(state.main.dims[1]/state.HEIGHT);
cam.setToOrtho(false, wi, state.HEIGHT);
```

***dims***:

```
dims[0]=Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
dims[1]=Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
```

Comment: Подскажите, у вас в первой строке: 
ширина камеры = ширина экрана / (высота экрана / высота камеры); Правильно?

Comment: @АлексейЕфимов да

Comment: Не могу разобраться. Я добавил изображение с описанием моей проблемы. Может описание вашего решения на примере изображения станет для меня  понятнее.

Comment: @АлексейЕфимов не использовать разные разрешения, у меня state.HEIGHT всегда 120 (перечитайте мой ответ еще раз, там ширина подгоняется на основании отношения сторон)

Comment: Ага, то есть я должен забыть про разрешения экранов устройств. Я прописываю размер "игрового" экрана, к примеру, width = 480; height = 800; Тогда, я помощью вашей реализации я должен получить: ширина камеры = ширина экрана устройства / (высота экрана устройства / height); И после этого предать камере полученную ширину и, ранее объявленную height, т.е. 800

Comment: @АлексейЕфимов забыть про разрешение, да, но из-за этого может появиться зернистость на экранах высокого разрешения. Мне это побоку, т.к. делаю пиксельные игры, а вот вам, похоже, надо будет скакать от самого большого разрешения...

Comment: Да, я планирую использовать хорошо прорисованную графику и box2d (конвертация пикселей в метры - еще одна моя головная боль). Значит я должен рисовать спрайты в ~ xhdpi?

Comment: @АлексейЕфимов скорее всего...

Comment: Спасибо, Вы здорово помогли)

Comment: @АлексейЕфимов надеюсь, у вас всё получится как и планируете.