# Как растянуть игру вверх для нестандартного соотношения экрана телефона?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

Нужна формула для растягивания вверх на нестандартных экранах без потери качества.
Такая, чтобы она растягивала верхнюю часть игры от стандартов в 16:9 до 21:9 (телефоны sony)

без использования viewport

Comment: То что решили поделиться решением это хорошо. Но нужно оформить вопрос как следует. Как можно подробнее опишите проблему, задайте точный вопрос. Это позволит другим людям предложить свои варианты решения и облегчит поиск будущим участникам.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`realWidth` - реальная высота у телефона

`Width` используется для масштабирования элементов по x

`HEIGHT` по y

```
public static float WIDTH;
public static float HEIGHT;
public static float realHeight;

{
    WIDTH = 720f;
    HEIGHT = 1280f;
}

public GameField(Main main) {
    this.main = main;


    realHeight = Gdx.app.getGraphics().getHeight() / (Gdx.app.getGraphics().getWidth() / WIDTH);

    camera = new OrthographicCamera(WIDTH, realHeight);
    stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(WIDTH, realHeight, camera));}
```

Comment: Должно помочь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/904054/257726